# Self Constency of the Extended Real Number System

Tags: real-numbers, number-systems

I'm reading the section on the extended real number system from Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, where he introduces the numbers $\infty$ and $-\infty$ and defines how they operate with finite numbers. My intuition is that in general, it's dangerous to expand a set with some operation and then define how the operation acts on the new elements because this opens the door to contradiction with the already established laws from the original set.

For example, if we wanted to expand the Klein four-group $K = \{1,a,b,ab\}$ by introducing an additional element $c$ and defining, say, $ac = ca := b$ and $bc = cb := a$, then we would be able to deduce $abc = a^2 = 1$, and now $ab$ has two inverses. How can we be absolutely certain that nothing equally pathological  happens when we introduce $\infty$ and $-\infty$ into the real numbers, or if we expand the complex numbers by adding the single point $\infty$?

Comment: No contradictions lurking. Just, like your extension of the Klein four-group is not a group, the extended real number system is not a field. But it's still useful.

Comment: It is not even a group, neither under addition nor multiplication anymore.

Comment: We can model the extended real line, using the real numbers, in the following way: Each real number is the set, which only element is the constant sequence equal to that number, $\infty$ is the set of all unbounded increasing sequences, $-\infty$ is the set of unbounded decreasing sequences. The arithmetic operations are defined by applying the same operation to all pairs of sequences in each set being operated. Then one only needs to check all the axioms of real closed field for the sets representing ordinary real numbers and the extra axioms for the $\pm\infty$.

Comment: So, for example $0\cdot \infty$ means that we take the sequence $0,0,0...$ and multiply it, term by term, with any unbounded increasing sequence. The result is the sequence $0,0,0,...$. Therefore, $0\cdot\infty$ is the set consisting only of the sequence $0,0,0,...$. That is out model for $0$. So, $0\cdot\infty=0$ is satisfied in this model.

Comment: Topologically, this is the same as adding $\pm 1$ to $(-1,1)$ or adding a point $P$ to $S^2\setminus \{P\}$, neither of which is particularly problematic, and in my experience the main reason to consider the extended reals is topological (e.g. it's an ordered, compact extension of the reals)

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any contradictions introduced, because $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are not added to the real number system.  They are introduced as hyperreal numbers $^*\mathbb{R}$ where $$\mathbb{R}\subset{^*\mathbb{R}}$$ and $$\pm{\infty}\in{^*\mathbb{R}}$$ but $$\pm{\infty}\notin{\mathbb{R}}$$
I suppose the word "extended" is misleading.  $\mathbb{R}$ is not being modified, rather, a superset of $\mathbb{R}$ is introduced ($^*\mathbb{R}$).